# Page scrolls up when I fadein a div and fade out another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop, preventdefault

In http://albertanglada.es
I have this:

```
$('#ultimas,#populares').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.grupo').hide();
  var id=  'div' + $(this).attr('id');
  $('.grupo#'+id).fadeIn();
});
```

On http://albertanglada.es/js/custom.js
I use it to hide al .groupo elementes and show an specific element. It works, if you click on:
'Últimas añadidas' or 'Populares' in the middle of the page you'll see that some boxes are show/hidden. The problem is that also the page scrolls up if you are on the bottom. I don't want to scroll up the page when those span are clicked.

```
<span class="left current tooltip" id="ultimas">Últimas añadidas</span> 
<span class="top" id="populares">Populares</span>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you not use `preventDefault()` since it isn't fully supported by IE. Either do a `return false;` or `if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); else e.returnValue = false;`

Comment: You will need to wrap your elements with a div that can "force" the height of the page even though its child gets hidden.

Comment: @xbonez the `preventDefault()` method is jQuery and is supported cross browser -> http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because the wrapper `feed-panel-wrapper` has no height - so when you hide its content it shrinks to `0px` height ... give the div a `height` or `min-height`

```
#feed-panel-wrapper {
   min-height: 300px;
}
```